# Issue with updating a record in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I did go through other posts that dealt this issue. But I couldn't find much with regard to my problem. Hope somebody can help. My issue is...I am having a certain edited record that I want to display in my `tableview`. For that I want to update that entry in Core-Data also. I am not able to figure out how that can be done.

This is how I am bringing the edited data in tableview and saving in Core Data. The updation has to be done somewhere in between but I am not able to figure out exactly how and where..?

```
@IBAction func saveToMainEditViewController (segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let detailViewController = segue.source as! EditCategoriesTableViewController
    let index = detailViewController.index
    let modelString = detailViewController.editedModel //Edited model has the edited string

    let myCategory1 = Category(context: self.context)
    myCategory1.categoryName = modelString
    mangObjArr[index!] = myCategory1     

    //Saving to CoreData
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Category", in: managedContext)
    let category = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)

    category.setValue(myCategory1.categoryName, forKeyPath: "categoryName")
    category.setValue(myCategory1.categoryId, forKey: "categoryId")
    do {

        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

Comment: Rather than updating you are creating a new record. You have to **fetch** the record, update it and save it back.

Comment: I am sorry @vadian...maybe because of my inexperience...but I'm not able to exactly figure out how thats done..:( .

Comment: Please read the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) to get some experience.

Comment: I have fetched the records in one place but how updating can be done that's what I'm confused with..did go through similar question from other stack users but they weren't of much help to my problem...

Answer (score 0):

## Steps:

1. Understand basic concepts
2. Fetch Record
3. Update Record
4. Save context

### Concepts:

- This is just a crude explanation, the proper explanation is in the link below.
- Though it is time consuming, please refer to the link below, it will help you understand CoreData. If you don't understand you will encounter a lot of problems later on.

#### Entity:

- In the core data model you can create entities, these are the tables.

#### Managed Object:

- This is the class representation of the entity
- Each instance of this class would represent a single row in the table.

#### Managed Object Context:

- Imagine managed object context like a piece of paper / scratch pad
- The managed objects are created / updated / deleted on a specific managed object context.
- You can save / discard the changes made to a managed object context.

#### Not Thread Safe:

- When ever you perform anything on a managed object context, make sure you use within `context.performAndWait { }`. This will ensure that context operations are performed on the context's queue (thread).

### Fetch and Update:

```
func fetch() {

    let request : NSFetchRequest< Category> = Category.fetchRequest()

    //Predicate builds the where clause to filter records
    //This is a sample, so edit based on your requirement
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "categoryID = %@", argumentArray: [10])

    context.performAndWait {

        do {
            let categories = try context.fetch(request)

            //Update
            for category in categories {
                category.name = "aaa"
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("error = \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

### Save:

```
func save() {

    if context.hasChanges {

        context.performAndWait {

            do {
                context.save()
            }
            catch {
                print("Save error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Reference:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @user1046037. But I'm having an issue..in this line let categories = try context.fetch(request), I'm getting categories an null..not sure why this is happening...

Comment: comment out `request.predicate` assignment. It is just an example. It is a filter condition that says categoryID = 10. So just comment it out and try

Comment: It is updating, @user1046037..Thanks...but a new issue is like if I have 2 entries in the tableview and I edit just one of them, then both the entries are updated(the one I didn't edit also)...

Comment: @User.bw each nsmanagedobject represents a single record in the context. So if you update one instance one record would be updated. It is up to you to decide how you want to build a unique field and then use the predicate to query based on that field. Learning just by asking questions might not be the best approach. Please read the documentation.